Legendre expansion of $ \frac{1}{(r^2 + R^2 - 2Rr \cos\gamma)^{3/2}} $ via generating function
I was asked to prove that the following equations are equivalent:
$\Phi_1(\vec{r}) = \frac{R(r^2 - R^2)}{4\pi} \int d\Omega' \frac{V(\theta', \varphi')}{(r^2 + R^2 - 2Rr \cos\gamma)^{3/2}},$ and $\Phi_2(\vec{r}) = \sum_{l=0}^\infty \sum_{m=-l}^l A_{lm} \left(\frac{R}{r}\right)^{l+1} Y_{lm}(\theta, \varphi)$ with $A_{lm} = \int d\Omega' \, Y_{lm}^*(\theta', \varphi') V(\theta', \varphi')$.
My first thought was to look at the Legendre-Fourier Series expansion of the term $h(r,\gamma)= \frac{1}{(r^2 + R^2 - 2Rr \cos\gamma)^{3/2}} $, considering that it is closely related to the generating funtion of the Legendre Polynomials. First I took the generating function: $\frac{1}{\sqrt{1 - 2xt + t^2}} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} P_n(x) t^n$ and differentiated it with respect to t, which gives: $\frac{\partial}{\partial t} \left( \frac{1}{\sqrt{1 - 2xt + t^2}} \right) = \frac{x - t}{(1 - 2xt + t^2)^{3/2}}.$ and $\frac{\partial}{\partial t} \sum_{l=0}^\infty t^l P_l(x) = \sum_{l=0}^\infty l t^{l-1} P_l(x).$
This is where y problems start to come, because to get to an expression for $h(r,\gamma)$ I would have to divide by $x-t$, which is a factor that doesn't cancel out. I asked the very untrustworthy ChatGPT, it said that it could just be ignored. I was wondering if there was any other way to prove the equivalence or to find the series expansion of $h(r,\gamma)$

Use http://dlmf.nist.gov/18.12.E4 and http://dlmf.nist.gov/14.3.iv
